# What does it means when you have "sql_exit_invoked" in System Health?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, extended-events

I'm having problems with one of my SQL Server 2016 Standard servers. I have 8 production servers and this one is the only one who crashes randomly without having any trace in the log.

I have system_health enabled on it. I noticed that I have a row in system health witch is "sql_exit_invoked".

[image: system_health_sql_exit_invoked]

I'm trying to find more informations on that row. What does it means?
The only info I found over the internet is that it happens when SQLExit() is called and that it's logged only since SQL 2012. (link available [on msdn website](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/10/54/84/57/XE_Events_per_SQLVersion.htm) )

[image: sql_exit_description]

So my question is : Should I worry to see this in my log? I find this only on my problematic server and not on any of the other 7 servers. (All of them are SQL Server 2016 Standard edition)

Can anybody give me more information on this?

Comment: Since the event is only generated at shutdown, perhaps it has rolled off of the other server traces? FYI, the possible values are `FAST_SHUTDOWN`, `NICE_SHUTDOWN`, `ORDERLY_SHUTDOWN`, `SHUTDOWN_NOT_SET` according to `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_xe_map_values WHERE name = 'sql_shutdown_option';`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extended Events are pretty poorly documented.

Debug channel extended events are even more poorly documented.

Based on my testing, you'll need to use the "shutdown_option" value from those event entries as a clue for where to look next.  Here's what they mean in my limited testing:

- `ORDERLY_SHUTDOWN`

  - restart or stop the service cleanly (using Config Manager, Services snap in, etc)
  - restart Windows cleanly (start menu -> shutdown / restart)
- `NICE_SHUTDOWN` - stop the service using the `SHUTDOWN;` T-SQL command
- `FAST_SHUTDOWN` - stop the service using the `SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT;` T-SQL command

Note that I also tried the following, and they did not register *anything* in the Extended Events session:

- shutdown Windows by holding down the power button
- kill the sqlservr.exe process from the Task Manager

I was unable to get the `SHUTDOWN_NOT_SET` version of the event to fire, so that one remains a mystery.

---

In your screenshot, I can see that ORDERLY_SHUTDOWN is the option in your scenario. In that case, since this seems to imply a clean shutdown of the service or Windows PC, I would look into the Windows Event Viewer "System" log and see why the machine is being restarted, or what service / component is issuing a SHUTDOWN command to the SQL Server serevice.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, that helps me a lot! Then I know that in this particular case I don't need to worry since the OS was probably restarted (I'll validate that with the IT team)